# Why does Windows service not autostart?

Tags: .net, windows, service

We have a Windows service written in C# (.Net3.5). When running it works perfectly. However our support people report that whilst it can always be successfully be started manually, it will not always autostart when Windows is rebooted.

I gather that this may be related to other services (on which it is dependant) not themselves having started, but as far as I can see, apart from its own login the service code isn't dependant on anything else (the service properties tab reports no dependencies). Also the first line of the service OnStart method is a Thread.Sleep(60000) to ensure all other services have had a chance to start. The server is Windows Server 2008 R1, so by my reckoning 60 seconds should be more than enough.

My questions are:

1. How can I be clear about its dependencies?
2. Are there any other well-known reasons for .Net services not auto-starting?

TIA

Comment: This might be help full to you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Sleeping in OnStart is a really bad idea - the thread that's calling OnStart doesn't belong to you - you're meant to get things started and exit OnStart in a timely fashion. Also, you won't see anything in service dependencies unless *you* have told windows about your dependencies.

Comment: Okay, perhaps that was bad advice (from another  question/answer on this forum). But how do I know what the 'dependencies' are? The code doesn't access anything other logging into Sql Server (which may on the same machine), and it doesn't require any other Windows services itself as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the windows service start type to "ServiceStartMode.Automatic" should help.

```
serviceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
```

This line of code tells the operating system to start the concerned windows service during system start-up. Also, if an automatically started service depends on a manually started service, the manually started service is also started automatically at system startup. **So you shouldn't need a Thread.Sleep.** You can also have a look at below article on how to assign other service dependencies to a windows service: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/adding-service-dependency-on-a-windows-service-through-regis/

Comment: Thanks, but it is already set to automatic. The problem is that it doesn't always automatically start. "... it will not always autostart when Windows is rebooted..."